# problem when creating UITextField programmatically iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I'm struggling when i try to create 11 text fields programmatically. The problem is that the text fields doesn't show up. I'm creating them in the `viewDidLoad` method.

Here's the code i'm using:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // Determine some basic info
    int numberOfTextfields = 11;
    int textfieldHeight = 40;
    int textfieldWidth = 200;


    // Create the UIScrollView
    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, numberOfTextfields*textfieldHeight,textfieldWidth)];


    // Create all the textfields
    NSMutableArray *textfields = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:
                                  (NSUInteger)numberOfTextfields];
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfTextfields; i++) {
        UITextField *field = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:
                              CGRectMake(0,i*textfieldHeight,textfieldHeight,textfieldWidth)];

        [scrollView addSubview:field];
        [textfields addObject:field];
    }

    [super viewDidLoad];

}
```

Any clues on why they don't show up?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you put the scrollview itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to never add `scrollView` as a subview.

---

Your textFields were atually hidden because you never set the border style.  Try this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // Determine some basic info
    int numberOfTextfields = 11;
    int textfieldHeight = 40;
    int textfieldWidth = 200;


    // Create the UIScrollView
    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, textfieldWidth,numberOfTextfields*textfieldHeight)];
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(numberOfTextfields*textfieldWidth, textfieldHeight);

    // Create all the textfields
    NSMutableArray *textfields = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:
                                  (NSUInteger)numberOfTextfields];
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfTextfields; i++) {
        UITextField *field = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,i*textfieldHeight,textfieldWidth,textfieldHeight)];
        field.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        [scrollView addSubview:field];
        [textfields addObject:field];
    }

    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: i tried [self.view addSubview:scrollView]; but it didn't work that's why i removed it from the code.

Comment: border style... ok thanks. One question: how can i separate the textfields from eachother?

Comment: Just add some padding. When you create your `UITextField`, do this: `UITextField *field = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, i*textfieldHeight+10, textfieldWidth, textfieldHeight)];`.  Be sure to increase the `contentSize` of the scroll view appropriately.

Comment: that's exactly what i tried and it didn't work, i only got padding before the first field not in between them. i guess i will make a new question about this when i give up searching

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your `UIScrollView` to your view *and* to setup its content area, as it doesn't manage it automagically (as you might have expected).

Answer (score 0):

you need to add your scroll view to your view controller. if it is allocated,
else do this
`self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake (0,0,320,460)]` 
add this line at the end `[self.view addSubview: scrollView]`

Answer (score 0):

Check this code.....frame parameters are(x,y,width,height)

```
    int numberOfTextfields = 11;
    int textfieldHeight = 40;
    int textfieldWidth = 200;


    // Create the UIScrollView
    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,textfieldWidth,numberOfTextfields*textfieldHeight)];


    // Create all the textfields
    NSMutableArray *textfields = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:
                                  (NSUInteger)numberOfTextfields];
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfTextfields; i++) {
        UITextField *field = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:
                              CGRectMake(0,i*textfieldHeight,textfieldWidth,textfieldHeight)];
        field.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        [scrollView addSubview:field];
        [textfields addObject:field];
    }
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
    [super viewDidLoad];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. Textfields are added and you can scroll the textview.

`int numberOfTextfields = 11;
int textfieldHeight = 40;
int textfieldWidth = 200;`

UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,textfieldWidth,numberOfTextfields*textfieldHeight)];
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(textfieldWidth, numberOfTextfields*textfieldWidth+10);

NSMutableArray *textfields = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:
                                  (NSUInteger)numberOfTextfields];

for(int i = 1; i < numberOfTextfields; i++) 
{
        UITextField *field = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:
                              CGRectMake(0,i*textfieldHeight,textfieldWidth,textfieldHeight)];
        field.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        [scrollView addSubview:field];
        [textfields addObject:field];
 }

[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
[super viewDidLoad];